# .Net Core Microservices different User Type based on IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, microservices, jwt

I am pretty new to Microservices and I am confused how to easily manage different type of user through all microservices.
Let start with thee Idea:
I have a list of `UserType` like : `SiteManager`, `Driver`, `Owner`, `SupportPerson`- this user types had specific properties each and using a single type `[USER]` is not relevant, but I can use roles to manage authorization for specific microservice -  this can be achieved using role manager. I would like to have different user types and Link Models to an `IdentityUser` like:

**Driver** `[UserId, LocationPoint, CurrentVehicle,LicenseNumber]`.
**Owner** `[UserId,Email...]`
**SiteManager**`[UserId,SiteId,Email,LocationPoint]`

*This 3 Types of User will handle 3 different Mobile Applications, and each application will bind to an API, or an AggregatorAPI*

**Identity.API**
`Login` (create user token and pass across Services).
 `Register` -> Register a `USER` and return `USER_ID`

**`Driver.API`** 
 `Register` a `Driver` (Call to Identity.API and get a valid User ID then create a Driver Entity), Do stuff on Driver.API

**`SiteManagerAPI`** 
 `Register` `SiteManager`(Call to Identity.API and get a valid User ID), create order for drivers

> Identity User should be a separate DB

So my questions is: Can I call my `IdentityAPI` microservice to create and save a new `User`, then I can use this
UserId to link to a new Driver Or SiteManager or SupportPerson, and in the same time using Identity microservice to Manage `Authentification` and `Authorization`? Or maybe someone has any ideas how to handle a multi-user type scenario when for each user type we need a separate table.

Comment: I think you need check this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/

Comment: I have already checked about implementing authorization, i’m stuck at architecture level when i need different tables for each actor ( driver, manager) because they hold different properties. And question was: if im using microservices and having Identity and authorization in a separate service - on RegisterDriver in DriverApi - can i call IdentityApi to create for me a identity user and then map that userId to new Driver